# Question about convexity and kernel of a set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

There is a theorem on my notebook:

> Let E be linear normed space,$A,B\subset E$ are convex sets s.t.
>   $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $intA\neq 0$. There is linear bounded
>   functional that separates A and B.

its proof starts with: $x_o\in intA$ then $x_o\in Ker(A)$. so A is convex field.

how do we write $x_o\in intA \rightarrow x_o\in Ker(A)$?

we know $Ker(A):=${$x:x\in A$ for all $y\in E$ there is $\epsilon = \epsilon(x,y)>0$, for every  $|t|<\epsilon$, $x+ty\in A$}

and can you suggest me a book that includes this hahn-banach corollary?

Comment: If $x_0 \in \operatorname{int} A$, then there is an $r > 0$ with $B_r(x_0) \subset A$. But $B_r(x_0) = x_0 + B_r(0)$, so taking $\epsilon(x,y) = \frac{r}{1+\lVert y\rVert}$ suffices.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is a convex field, what do you mean by $\to$ above?

Comment: @copper.hat I found convex field definition such as "if M is convex subset and $Ker(M)\neq \emptyset $ M is called convex field

Comment: @lyme German? "Konvexer Körper"? That would be "convex body" then. Körper only becomes field when it is about the algebraic structure. (Similar for French, corps = body, unless it's algebra.)

Comment: @DanielFischer no, I'm not :) my teacher uses kolmogorov Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis russian second edition. (I couldnt find english version of it though, there is only spanish one.). on my notebook convex body defined as smallest convex set that includes M is called convex body of M.

Comment: The question wasn't whether you are, rather about the language. But that seems to be Russian (of which I know only a handful of words ;). The smallest convex set that contains $M$ is called the "convex hull" of $M$ in standard terminology. So there seems to be a translation issue.

Comment: @DanielFischer my bad. I should say "shell" or "cover" for the last def I wrote. sorry for my ignorance. we take 1+||y|| instead of ||y||, because y can equal to 0? and it is intA=ker(A), right? do we need convexity of A for this? and lastly could you suggest me a simple book for functional analysis which includes this matters :)

Comment: No reason to apologise for not being familiar with the terminology in a foreign language. Yes, we add something positive to $\lVert y\rVert$ to avoid division by $0$. If you make a case distinction, you can use $\lVert y\rVert$ for nonzero $y$. No, you don't necessarily have $\operatorname{int} A = \ker A$. The interior is always contained in the kernel (well, I guess the term would actually be "core"), but the inclusion can be strict. I'm afraid I can't recommend a book for these matters. IIRC, that version was explicitly included in L. Schwartz, Topologie generale et Analyse fonctionelle.

Comment: But that is long out of print, as far as I know. You can get it with a little abstraction from the versions included in Rudin (Functional Analysis) and in Meise/Vogt (Introduction to Functional Analysis). But I would call neither of these books simple.